# filter datagridview rows

Tags: c#, text, datagridview, filter

Hello I have a datagridview that already has many, many rows added to it. I also have a textbox that I want to filter the rows out of the datagridview rows if they do not match. I somehow want to connect the textbox to a column to show AND hide the rows. The table was populated using:

```
public void readExcelFile()
{
    string connectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0; Data Source = " + Properties.Settings.Default.excelFilePath + "; Extended Properties = \"Excel 8.0;HDR=Yes;IMEX=1\";";

    string query = String.Format("select * from [{0}$]", "Batch Export");

    OleDbDataAdapter dataAdapter = new OleDbDataAdapter(query, connectionString);

    DataSet dataSet = new DataSet();
    dataAdapter.Fill(dataSet);

    resultsGrid.DataSource = dataSet.Tables[0];                
}
```

Now when I start typing "John" into the textbox and the first column is "Name", I want all the rows whose Name cell doesn't start with "J", then "Jo", etc. when I delete characters, I want the rows to come back. Is this possible? I've done this before using SQL queries to a DB, but this source is different. And I had to clear the table on every textChanged event. There are about 20k rows here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before you assign the Table to the resultGrid.DataSource, you can use DataTable.Select:

```
var strExpr = "CustomerFirstName = 'John' AND OrderCount > 2";
var strSort = "OrderCount DESC";

// Use the Select method to find all rows matching the filter.
foundRows = ds.Table[0].Select(strExpr, strSort);
```

Or you can use DataView:

```
ds.Tables[0].DefaultView.RowFilter = strExpr;
```

Answer (score 0):

We can used a binding source to filter the data.

```
 private BindingSource dashBoardBindingSource = new BindingSource();
 dashBoardBindingSource.DataSource= dataSet.Tables[0]; 
 resultsGrid.DataSource=dashBoardBindingSource;

 string filterCriteria = "CustomerFirstName={0}";
 dashBoardBindingSource.Filter=string.Format(CultureInfo.CurrentCulture, filterCriteria, textboxName.text);
```