# Select Rows with check box set

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

I need to display only rows, where "availability" column (which is checkbox), is selected. How can I select only those rows?

```
private void checkBox1_Checked {
   foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dataGridView1.Rows)
   {
       if (Convert.ToBoolean(row.Cells["availability"].Value) != true)
       {
           //row.Visible = false;
           //exception

                   ...
```

I have tried to do something like code above, but it does not have .visible property

My task is to delete all unchecked rows when one "main" checkbox is unchecked. But only from DataGridView, not from DataSet.

Comment: take a look at 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10543782/filter-datagridview-rows

Comment: Isn't this data grid attached to a data source?

Comment: datagridview is attached to dataset, and takes data from local database. but i need to filter this data locally, without new query. Thx, anyway

Answer (score 0):

You could try using a list as the datagridview's datasource:

```
public class MyRecord
{
    public bool Availability { get; set; }
    public int Field1 { get; set; }
    public string Field2 { get; set; }
    ...
}

MyRecords = new BindingList<MyRecord>();

foreach (var row in dataSet1)
{
    MyRecords.Add(new MyRecord { Availability  = false, Field1 = ... });
    MyRecords.Add(new MyRecord { Availability  = false, Field1 = ... });
}

dataGridView1.DataSource = MyRecords;
```

Then you could just do:

```
var selectedRows = MyRecords.Where(r => r.Availability).ToList();
foreach (var item in selectedRows)
{
    MyRecords.Remove(item);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As I understand you want keep in `Datagridview` only checked rows.
I assume/hope every row in `datasource` have some unique `ID` value.
If so then you can get unique ID list of checked rows

```
List<Int32> checkedRowID = this.datagridview1.Rows.Cast<DataGridViewRow>()
       .Where((rw) => Convert.ToBoolean(rw.Cells["availability"].Value) == true)
       .Select((row) => Convert.ToInt32(row.Cells["uniqueColumnName"].Value))
       .ToList();
```

Then if "main" checkbox is unchecked use this list to filter original `DataTable`

```
if(maincheckbox.Checked != true)
    this.datagridview1.DataSource = originDataTable.AsEnumerable()
        .Where((dr) => checkedRowID.Contains(dr.Field<Int32>("uniqueColumnName")))
        .CopyToDataTable();
else
    this.datagridview1.DataSource = originDataTable;
```

Or you can use `DataTable.Select` method for filtering

```
String query = String.Format("uniqueColumnName IN ({0})",
                             String.Join(",", uniqueIDs ));
this.dgv.DataSource = dt.Select(query).CopyToDataTable();
```